# How to update a datatable with another datatable?

Tags: c#

I want to join two datatables using something like this:

```
update u
set datatable1.column["state"]= datatable2.column["state"]
from datatable1 u
    inner join datatable2 s on
        u.column["header"]= s.column["header"]
```

what is the syntax in linq?

Comment: Here it is: [Introduction of LINQ To Dataset](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/linq_dataset.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not try to modify something from within LINQ **queries**. It's bad practise if LINQ queries cause side-effects. But you can collect the informations you need to update:

```
var updateQuery = from r1 in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                  join r2 in datatable2.AsEnumerable()
                  on r1.Field<string>("header") equals r2 .Field<string>("header")
                  select new { r1, r2 };
foreach(var x in updateQuery)
{
    x.r1.SetField("state", x.r2.Field<string>("state"));
}
```

The query is really just a *query*, it is only executed once at the `foreach`, but also everytime you will access the `updateQuery`-variable due to LINQ's deferred execution. If you don't want this you have to create a collection, f.e. with `ToList` or `ToArray`.